# iAds giving ADInternalErrorCode=3, inventory unavailable 100% of the time

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, iad

I have an iAd banner and fullscreen ad, that both were working just last night. The banner was loading much more often than the fullscreen ad, but they were coming up at least some of the time. This morning i have been at it for 3 hours and not seen a single iAd displayed on my iPad 2. I keep getting the error

`Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo=0x49a4f0 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable}`

I know apple throws errors in for testing purposes but I have probably reloaded the whole app from a clean build 10 times, and run about 100 others.

Can any one tell me their experience with this, and if this is normal?

Also im running iOS 5.0.1 on my iPad 2

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check iTunes Connect and see if there is an updated iAd agreement you need to accept (you should see it when you click the "iAd network" link).  This happened to me too, and when I accepted the new agreement, the iAds started working again.

Comment: Good answer! That helped me, too! Now I just have to reset all my banking information again . . . ugh!