# iAd not displaying from last few days

Tags: ios, iad, inventory, operation

**iAd error**:

```
    Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable" 
UserInfo=0x118bb420 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable}
```

Can you please tell me its my coding problem or it is the problem form Apple site?

I am allocating iAd object in App Delegate and delegates are also in App Delegate. Here is the code:-

```
AppDelegate *appDel=(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake( 0.0,300,320,50);
appDel.adBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
appDel.adBanner.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
appDel.adBanner.currentContentSizeIdentifier =      ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
[appDel.adBanner setHidden:YES];
appDel.adBanner.delegate = self;

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    AppDelegate *app=(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSLog(@"iAd load");
    app.adBanner.frame=CGRectMake( 0.0,300,320,50);
    app.adBanner.hidden=NO;
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    AppDelegate *app=(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSLog(@"iAd error: %@", error);
    app.adBanner.hidden=YES;
    app.adBanner.frame=CGRectMake( 0.0,350,0,0);
}
```

Then I am adding banner in Abstract `UIViewConroller` Class

```
CGFloat y=0;
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    y=result.height;
}
AppDelegate *app=(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
CGRect rect2 = CGRectMake( 0.0,y-50,320,50);
app.adBanner.frame =rect2;
UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication     sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
[topController.view addSubview:app.adBanner];
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403951/iads-giving-adinternalerrorcode-3-inventory-unavailable-100-of-the-time?rq=1 refer this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on simulator? Probably the issue lies in the domain when you test iAds in iOS simulator. Try testing on device, if the issue persists add some code in question to help us understand where the actual problem is

Comment: Problem is still there, even on device also. I added my code. Thanx to you if you could help me.